# How to run Shell script having ssh commands using cron job in kubernetes

Tags: shell, kubernetes, ssh, cron

I want to run shell script which are having ssh commands in the file using cron job in the kubernetes

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo copying files from edge node to batch pods;
ssh -q userid@<hostname>"kubectl config use-context testnamespace";
ssh -q userid@<hostname>"kubectl scale statefulsets testpod --replicas=1";
```

when I executing it manually by going pod, it is throwing me error `"ssh command not found"` and by triggering job throwing me `permission denied` message.

can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Kindly check if `ssh` utility is installed in your pod and if you have permission to create a kube job.. if not then change the role or clusterrole for your user.

Comment: Please, follow @anmolagrawal sugestions and let us know. If you have any trouble don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Do you mean we need to install  ssh utility in docker? and we can use them in pod? can you guide me how to install ssh in docker from linux server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message (`ssh command not found`)  indicates a lack of ssh client in your pod. In the comments, you are mentioning docker so I assume you are using your docker image.

To install SSH in your docker container you have to run apt-get or yum or any other package manager according to our Linux Distribution and this needs to be expressed in your Dockerfile.

Here is an example of how to achieve this:

```
# A basic apache server. To use either add or bind mount content under /var/www

FROM ubuntu:12.04

MAINTAINER Kimbro Staken version: 0.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data

ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data

ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

In this example, we are installing apache on a ubuntu image. In your scenario you need to run something similar to this:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```